# How to set two FilterString condtion on code Reports Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, report

am using devexpress winforms reports, I can able to set one filterString condition in code, this code is working successful

```
report.FilterString = "CompanyId =" + compid;
```

and

```
DetailReport.FilterString = "CompanyId=" + compid;
```

But now I need to set for two conditions I tried this code but it didn't filter display all 
values.

```
report.FilterString = "[CompanyId = " + compid +"] AND [ InvoiceStatus =" + status + "]";
```

Help me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all. Finally solved by this code and working fine for two filters using correct string formats.

```
report.FilterString = "InvoiceStatus = '" + status + "' AND CompanyId = " + compid;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest filter syntax looks like this: `"[FieldName] = Value"`.

Thus, change your code as follows:

```
report.FilterString = string.Format("[CompanyId] = {0} AND [InvoiceStatus] = {1}", compid, status);
```

Comment: Hi, Still facing same error empty report that condition didn't work. If i leave InvoiceStatus and Filter only companyId means then no problem. If I leave CompanyId and filter only InvoiceStatus means nothing will displays again empty report. I may think problem in string format this filter string working for int only ? is it ?

Comment: Hi yeah that string in filter only not working this condition working fine `report.FilterString = string.Format("[CompanyId] = {0} AND [CustomerId] = {1}", compid, custid);`

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your `InvoiceStatus` type or value... What DevExpress guys says about this?

Comment: They simply said refer this link https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_FilterStringtopic